# Входной аудио поток

Tags: java, javafx, аудио, float, byte

Здравствуйте, я захватываю звук с помощью микрофона. И сигнал получаю как массив байтов. Могу ли я записать сигнал и получить массив float ? И будет ли это тоже самое, что нормализация массива байтов от -1 до 1 ?